# Support Vector Machines: How can you generate higher dimensional data from lower ones?

Tags: svm

I recently read a post describing the Support Vector Machine theory and brought about some idea that says it throws data from `n` dimensions to some **higher** dimensional space.

[SVM description](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/15zrpp/please_explain_support_vector_machines_svm_like_i/)

I wanna know how can we *generate* more dimensional features from given `n` features?

Whats the basis of these **extra** dimensions? Won't these be dependent on the previous `n` dimensions, and if so how can we say that these are independent "dimensions"??

Comment: They're not independent, but they don't have to be; they merely have to make it easier to find separating hyperplanes.

Comment: As @Emre Said, they're not independent,  they're formed by combination of existing features to add another dimension

Comment: Okay. But still. Lets suppose I have some data points in a one-D line and I plot the line in a 3-D space. What extra help would these extra two dimensions possibly can give me? I mean the hyper plane would still be cutting the line on the point where I would have separated them out on the 1-D line itself? I mean the line in a 3-D space is still a line? What extra benefit I got from piloting it on a 3-D space?

Comment: Perhaps [this illustrative example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method#/media/File:Kernel_trick_idea.svg) will help. Adding a third dimension made the circular 2D boundary a 3D hyperplane.

Comment: Thanks @Emre.. This definitely improves my thinking about the SVMs. But as taking x^2 + y^2 as the third dimension is very specific for the problem. How would SVM know which dimension to use? I mean it could be (x^3)/(y^4) or ...etc. If taking all the combinations is what's refer to infinite dimension won't this be completely out of scope to computationally solve these??

Comment: You are conflating concepts. Infinite dimensional embeddings arise from the use of kernels, such as the radial basis function. You do not need to actually find the representation of the input in the kernel space, as the dependency is on _pairs_ of inputs through their inner product, which is what the kernel function returns. You _can_ learn a kernel optimized for your data set, but this is advanced and most people just try the kernels available in their software.

Comment: Thanks @Emre. I have thoroughly searched for the things you said and have a better understanding. (y)

Comment: If you like this subject the canonical reference is [Learning with Kernels](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/learning-kernels). Here are some recent papers on learning kernels: [Deep Kernel Learning](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v51/wilson16.html), [Stochastic Variational Deep Kernel Learning](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6425-stochastic-variational-deep-kernel-learning), [Overview of Deep Kernel Learning Based Techniques and Applications](http://bit.kuas.edu.tw/~jni/2016/vol1/JNI_2016_vol1_n3_001.pdf).Good luck.

Comment: Please don’t write answers in comments. It bypasses our quality measures by not having voting (both up and down) available on comments, as well as having other problems. Comments are for clarifying and improving the question; please don’t use them for other purposes.